# Adding custom validation for vat_id in the checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, validation

I have this plugin:

```
    public function afterProcess(
        LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {
     ...
             if(isset(
            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['vat_id']
        )){
            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['vat_id']
                ['validation']['validate-vat-id'] = 1;  // this doesn't work !!!
//            ['validation']['required-entry'] = 1;   // this works!!!!
        }
     ...
```

and this is my mixin:

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/discount': {
                'Vendor_Checkout/js/view/payment/discount': true
            },
            'mage/validation': {
                'Vendor_Checkout/js/validation-vat-id-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

and this is my `app/code/Vendor/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/validation-vat-id-mixin.js` file:

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    "use strict";

    return function () {
        $.validator.addMethod(
            'validate-vat-id',
            function (value) {
                console.log('hello custom validation');
                // Some custom validation stuff here
                return true;
            },
            $.mage.__('Your validation error message')
        );
    }
});
```

I'm not sure why this is not working :) . Can you give me some ideas what to try or to check ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create the file :

NameSpace/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

In it, I will insert rules for validation name = 'vat_id'.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
            <referenceBlock  name="checkout.root">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="vat_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="min_text_length" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                                                                            <item name="max_text_length" xsi:type="number">9</item>
                                                                            <item name="letters-only" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                            <item name="max-words" xsi:type="number">2</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Hi @Vishal , Thanks for your reply , but i don't get any validation of those , for the vat_id